# React native blur background dynamically

Tags: react-native, overlay, blur

Hi everyone I'm using Overlay element form react-native elemens package.I want to blur background on overlay. Overlay works fine but I can't make background blur.

`import {Overlay} from 'react-native-elements'`;

```
<Overlay
  overlayStyle={{ borderRadius: 20, width: "90%" }}
  isVisible={this.state.isOverlay}
  onBackdropPress={() => {
    this.toggleOverlay();
  }}
>
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView maxHeight={500} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <Box flex={1} borderRadius={30}>
      <Text>Give a Star</Text>
      <Box marginVertical={10} mr={55}>
        <StarRating
          disabled={false}
          starSize={48}
          emptyStarColor="#D6D6D6"
          maxStars={5}
          rating={this.state.starCount}
          selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
          fullStarColor={"#8EC4DC"}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</Overlay>;
```

Comment: Anyone ? just gotta blur

Comment: you can make use of react-native-blur library [here](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible to use a blur effect by relying solely on the stock Overlay.

I've used BlurView from expo to achieve the effect I was looking for here:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/blur-view/

Note: It doesn't really blur on android, but it is noted in their documentation:

`On iOS, it renders a native blur view. On Android, it falls back to a semi-transparent view.`

example:

```js
import { BlurView } from "expo-blur";

return (
    <View style={styles.behind}>
      <BlurView
        tint="dark"
        intensity={80}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          padding: 0,
        }}
      >
        <Text>Stuff on top</text>
      </BlurView>
      <Text>Stuff Behind</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```